# How to search for substring in array of JSON Field?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I'm using a `JSONField` provided by Django and I store this type of data in that field:

```
[
        {
            "number": 1,
            "text": "This text is about dogs"
        },
        {
            "number": 2,
            "text": "Only cats in this text here"
        },
        {
            "number": 3,
            "text": "However, this text does also contain dogs"
        },
    ]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is some sort of substring match - ie, if a person searches for the string `"dog"`, the result should return something like:

```
        {
            "number": 1,
            "text": "This text is about dogs"
        },
        {
            "number": 3,
            "text": "However, this text does also contain dogs"
        },
```

Looking at the Django docs, it seems possible to query for JSON fields, as such

```
Model.objects.filter(field__text__contains='dogs')
```

However, `contains`  only works for single dictionary values, not when there is an array of dictionaries.

Any tips? Either through the Django ORM or through Postgres straight up.

Comment: You might find a solution using JSONPATH queries, but it won't perform well. Use a normalized data model rather than JSON arrays, and the exercise will become simple and the query can be fast.

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed you have an ID column on the table you're searching and it's important to keep this information intact. What you want can only be done with Postgres's `jsonb` data type (At least, I can't think of another way) and you should probably rethink how you're storing it in the database if you're needing to search inside an array of json objects without any top-level keys to make it easier to search and reference in queries.

That said, here's my go at a base postgres query that searches the 'text' key value pair for matches and then removes the non-matching values.

```
WITH search_set AS (
        SELECT  t.id,
                t.js
        FROM ( VALUES (1,'[{"number": 1,"text": "This text is about dogs"},{"number": 2,"text": "Only cats in this text here"},
        {"number": 3,"text": "However, this text does also contain dogs"}]'::jsonb) 
        ) AS t(id,js) 
        WHERE jsonb_path_exists(js, '$.text[*] ? (@ like_regex "(dogs)" flag "i")') 
)
SELECT rs.id,
      jsonb_agg(arr.elem)
FROM search_set rs,
jsonb_array_elements(rs.js) AS arr(elem)
WHERE
    arr.elem::varchar ILIKE '%dog%'
    GROUP BY rs.id 
 ;
```